# Single direction edge detection

Tags: matlab, edge-detection

I'm trying to use edge detection to find an uneven horizontal edge that is always bright on top and dark on the bottom. I have had decent luck with canny edge detecting but keep picking up other edges which are dark on the top and light on the bottom. Is there any way in canny or some other standard MATLAB edge detection to specify a direction for edge detection?

Comment: I think simple `diff` instruction may work. Can you please upload the input image?

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
[Gx,Gy] = imgradientxy(myimage)
```

to get the directional image gradient. Then you would define some threshold for the image gradient in the direction you care about.

Comment: Yea but I'm not looking for just horizontal vs. vertical edges. I'm looking for horizontal edges specifically where the bright half of the edge is on the top of the horizontal edge and not those instances where the bright half is on the bottom.

Comment: @user3470496 if the bright is on the bottom, then the direction is reversed. The gradient always points from the dark side to the bright side.